# Adding generic types to EnumMap

Tags: java

I'm trying to add instances to the following EnumMap:

```
class ActiveG<D extends GData, T extends GTemplate> {

    EnumMap<GStateType, GState<ActiveG<D,T>> map;
    ..
    ..
}

class TGData extends GData {...}
class TGTemplate extends GTemplate {....}

class ActiveTG extends ActiveG<TGData, TGTemplate> {

    // fails with compilation error
    super.states.put(GStateType.WAITING, new TGWaitingState<ActiveTG>(this));
    ...
    ...
}
```

The error I get:

```
The method put(GStateType, GState<ActiveG<TGData,TGTemplate>>) in the
type EnumMap<GStateType,GState<ActiveG<TGData,TGTemplate>>> is not 
applicable for the arguments (GStateType, TGWaitingState<ActiveTG>)
```

Can anyone try to help me figure out what's missing to make it work??
Thanks!

Comment: `EnumMap<Long, ...>`? What are you trying to do? Do you have some `enum Long {}` somewhere or are you trying to use `java.lang.Long` as a key in an `EnumMap`? Actually the code example doesn't make any sense because you are calling `super.states.put` but you've shown us the declaration for `EnumMap<...> map`. Please clarify and post correct code that reproduces the error. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sure...your map is not a GStateType, TGWaitingState<ActiveTG> type :).  You've defined your map as a Long, GState<...>, where's GStateType and   what is TGWaitingState<> ?

Comment: Sorry, did a bad copy paste - look at it now.
by the way, TGWaitingState inherits GState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In brief, Generics in Java is not covariance.

e.g. if you have

```
class Parent {...}

class Child extends Parent {...}
```

`Foo<Child>` is NOT a `Foo<Parent>`

Go back to your code:

your enum map in `ActiveTG` is expecting  `GState<ActiveG<TGData,TGTemplate>>` as value, but you are giving it a `TGWaitingState<ActiveTG>`, which is a `GState<ActiveTG>`.

Although `ActiveTG` is-a `ActiveG<TGData,TGTemplate>`, `GState<ActiveTG>` is NOT a `GState<ActiveG<TGData,TGTemplate>>`.

In order to solve it, you will need quite some change in the type params, like

```
class ActiveG<D extends GData, 
              T extends GTemplate, 
              E extends ActiveG<D,T>> {
     EnumMap<GStateType, GState<E>> map;
}
```

or simply make `map` with type `EnumMap<GStateType, GState<? extends ActiveG<D,T>>`.  This may not work very well in some situation, for example, you need to retrieve the result as a `GState<ActiveTG>` instead of `GState<ActiveG<D,T>>`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!! I learned something new from you !